# How to retrieve revert() reason for past transactions?

Tags: solidity, evm, geth-debugging, revert-opcode, openethereum

I run a geth/parity node for broadcasting user's transactions to Ethereum blockchain. Some of contract functions provide reasons for revert (see example below):

```
contract Example {
  function test (uint i) {
    require(i == 1, "ERROR_CODE")
  }
}
```

As I understand it, it is not possible to get revert reason string with eth_getTransactionReceipt. However, I still need to get the revert reason for failed transactions.

How do I get the revert reason ("ERROR_CODE" in the example above) for past failed transactions (at least for transactions in the last 20 blocks)?

Answer (score 12):

In solidity 0.4.22 the `require` and `revert` reason were added. As can be seen [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/3364/files#diff-6ec42630506b86abb9d7386116dd0e5bR85), they are abi-encoded as if it were a call to a function "Error(string)".

[This blog post](https://www.dhondt.tech/blog/2019/1/Web3j-retrieve-revert-reason.html) gives an example: an `eth_call` to a function

```
function myFunction(uint256 input) public view returns (uint256) {
    require(input >= 5, "myFunction only accepts arguments which are greather than or equal to 5");
    return input * input - 25;
}
```

with an invalid input argument (less than 5 in this example), will return

```
0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000476d7946756e6374696f6e206f6e6c79206163636570747320617267756d656e747320776869636820617265206772656174686572207468616e206f7220657175616c20746f203500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which is

```
0x08c379a0                                                       // Function selector
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 // Offset of string return value
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047 // Length of string return value (the revert reason)
6d7946756e6374696f6e206f6e6c79206163636570747320617267756d656e74 // first 32 bytes of the revert reason
7320776869636820617265206772656174686572207468616e206f7220657175 // next 32 bytes of the revert reason
616c20746f203500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // last 7 bytes of the revert reason
```

So decoding the returned string will give you the revert reason.

With Web3j this could be done like:

```
public Optional<String> getRevertReason(EthCall ethCall) {
    String errorMethodId = "0x08c379a0"; // Numeric.toHexString(Hash.sha3("Error(string)".getBytes())).substring(0, 10)
    List<TypeReference<Type>> revertReasonTypes = Collections.singletonList(TypeReference.create((Class<Type>) AbiTypes.getType("string")));

    if (!ethCall.hasError() && ethCall.getValue() != null && ethCall.getValue().startsWith(errorMethodId)) {
        String encodedRevertReason = ethCall.getValue().substring(errorMethodId.length());
        List<Type> decoded = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(encodedRevertReason, revertReasonTypes);
        Utf8String decodedRevertReason = (Utf8String) decoded.get(0);
        return Optional.of(decodedRevertReason.getValue());
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: So the `0x08c379a0`  is the signature of the `require()` function?

Comment: @Ender it's the signature of `Error(string)` —
```keccak256("Error(string)") == 08c379a0afcc32b1a39302f7cb8073359698411ab5fd6e3edb2c02c0b5fba8aa``` first 4 bytes is method sig: `08c379a0`

Answer (score 9):

I created an NPM package to handle this: [eth-revert-reason](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-revert-reason)

---

It is difficult to decode the revert reason in a general manner. Many different factors, such as Geth vs. Parity, web3.js vs ethers, etc. will result in different results for all the answers posted here. Some issues are:

1. For a Kovan transaction, you need a custom provider that exposes Parity `trace` methods.
2. Transactions may result in different messages depending on the context of the block they are called from. Because of this, you may need to be running a full-archival node in order to retrieve the correct error message.

In a happy-path case, the code to retrieve the revert reason is:

```
const provider = customProvider || ethers.getDefaultProvider(network)
const tx = await provider.getTransaction(txHash)
const code = await provider.call(tx)
```

While the code to produce the revert reason in the normal case is simple, the non-standard cases are surprisingly difficult to handle, however this package attempts to appease this.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes.

Comment: Just [saw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-revert-reason) that:  "...this works consistently with the Infura and Alchemy providers." :(

Answer (score 8):

Using eth_Call to execute function:

```
Example.test(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002)
```

of Example contract we will receive
following reply from geth node:

> 0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a4552524f525f434f444500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Which gives following output arguments:

```
arg0: 0x08c379a
arg1: 0x20
arg2: 0x0a
arg3: 0x4552524f525f434f444500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

**where arg3 == 'ERROR_CODE'** (utf8 + hex encoded)

So, I suppose, for fully syched node we can use eth_Call with explicit indication of failed transaction block number:

```
{
  method: "eth_Call",
  params: [
    {
      from: '0x...address',
      to: '0x...contract',
      value: '0x0',
      data: "0x29e99f070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"
    }, 
    FALED_TRANSACTION_BLOCK_NR
  ]
}
```

However this is not convenient way of getting error codes.. Is there any other way?

Comment: I can't do the edit because it's too short, but notice that arg0 is actually `0x08c379a0` (notice the trailing 0), which represents the 8 first bytes of the hash of Error(string).

Answer (score 6):

After being really annoyed for a long time I wrote a bash script to fetch the revert reason from geth by a tx hash:

https://gist.github.com/gluk64/fdea559472d957f1138ed93bcbc6f78a

Comment: this  is really helpful,
could you also help me do the same for metamask failed transactions

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible with `go-ethereum`. Tested with a simulated blockchain backend.

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

// other code using the following...

func errorReason(ctx context.Context, b ethereum.ContractCaller, from common.Address, tx *types.Transaction, blockNum *big.Int) (string, error) {
    msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        From:     from,
        To:       tx.To(),
        Gas:      tx.Gas(),
        GasPrice: tx.GasPrice(),
        Value:    tx.Value(),
        Data:     tx.Data(),
    }
    res, err := b.CallContract(ctx, msg, blockNum)
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "CallContract")
    }
    return unpackError(res)
}

var (
    errorSig            = []byte{0x08, 0xc3, 0x79, 0xa0} // Keccak256("Error(string)")[:4]
    abiString, _        = abi.NewType("string", "", nil)
)

func unpackError(result []byte) (string, error) {
    if !bytes.Equal(result[:4], errorSig) {
        return "<tx result not Error(string)>", errors.New("TX result not of type Error(string)")
    }
    vs, err := abi.Arguments{{Type: abiString}}.UnpackValues(result[4:])
    if err != nil {
        return "<invalid tx result>", errors.Wrap(err, "unpacking revert reason")
    }
    return vs[0].(string), nil
}
```

After a transaction failed, you usually hold a `*types.Receipt` from `bind.WaitMined`, which has the field `BlockNumber`, so you know with which block number to call `errorReason`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to the ops question, but for all others that stumble over this question while searching for how to get the error reason generated by a failed solidity require in javascript:

It depends on wether you are using web3.js or ethers.js to call the contract

web3:

```js
  // invalid index, should trigger: require(_i < Donors.length, "index _i out of bounds");
  const donorIndex = 99;
  // The Contract object
  let faucet = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddr);
  try {
    let r = await faucet.methods.getDonorAddress(donorIndex).call().catch((e) => { throw (e); });
    console.log("Donor Address result:", r);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e && e.reason) {
      console.log("contract require failed with:", e.reason);
    }
  }
```

ethers:

```js
  // invalid index, should trigger: require(_i < Donors.length, "index _i out of bounds");
  const donorIndex = 99;
  // Use a read-only signer as we call only view/pure functions
  const signer = new ethers.VoidSigner(fromAddress, provider);
  // The Contract object
  const faucet = new ethers.Contract(contractAddr, abi, signer);
  try {
    let r = await faucet.getDonorAddress(donorIndex).catch((e) => { throw (e); });
    console.log("Donor Address result:", r);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e && e.reason) {
      console.log("contract require failed with:", e.reason);
    }
  }
```

Results:

```bash
[kim@manjaro4 nodejs]$ ./getRequireErrorMessageWeb3.js 
contract require failed with: value out of range

[kim@manjaro4 nodejs]$ ./getRequireErrorMessageEthers.js 
contract require failed with: index _i out of bounds

[kim@manjaro4 nodejs]$ npm list web3
web3_faucet@1.0.0 /home/kim/source/Energi-Smart-Contract-Tutorial/nodejs
└── web3@1.3.1 
[kim@manjaro4 nodejs]$ npm list ethers
web3_faucet@1.0.0 /home/kim/source/Energi-Smart-Contract-Tutorial/nodejs
└── ethers@5.0.24
```

The full source is at: [Github - Energi3 smartcontract tutorial](https://github.com/kimxilxyong/Energi-Smart-Contract-Tutorial/tree/master/nodejs)

TL;DR: Use ethers.js