# What is the layout of returndata from returndatacopy opcode?

Tags: solidity, assembly, memory, revert-opcode, returndata

I am attempting to perform operations on returned data from `delegatecall` opcode using a similar familiar proxy pattern:

```
assembly {
    let ptr := mload(0x40) // load empty memory address pointer
    calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize()) // copy calldata to memory
    mstore(0x40, add(ptr, calldatasize())) // reset free memory pointer

    let outptr := add(ptr, calldatasize()) // new free memory pointer for output location
    success := delegatecall(gas(), implementation, ptr, calldatasize(), outptr, 0) // delegate call passing all calldata returning 0 on failure, 1 on success

    returndatacopy(outptr, 0, returndatasize())
```

The resulting returned data looks something like this (including my returned revert reason):

```
0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f6e6f7420696d706c656d656e74656400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000....
```

So to help break it down, this is as far as I've understood this layout.

- There is an initial 4-bytes: `0x08c379a0`
- Then follows a 32-byte memory slot filled with: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020` which itself contains a value = 32
- Then follows the next 32-byte slot with the expected data; an array length: `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f` = 15 bytes
- And the array itself, in this case a string, in the next 32-byte slot: `0x6e6f7420696d706c656d656e7465640000000000000000000000000000000000` - "not implemented" which is my error string 15-bytes long, the rest of the slot 0s.
- Then follows 0's for the rest of the 100-byte-long return data.

My questions are:

- What does the leading 4-bytes `0x08c379a0` mean? There is a different leading 4-bytes it seems depending on what the returned data is.
- What is the preceding padded `0x20` that appears before my error message array?
- Why is the total returndata length 100-bytes that is filled with mostly 0's where my reversion messages do not fill it? If I lengthen my revert return reasons beyond the 100-bytes, the returndata also lengthens accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/66173/29323) provides a complete view of the exact issue I stumbled upon here.

- `0x08c379a0` is the function signature of `Error(string)` which is what `require` or `revert` failures use.
- The `0x20` preceding the string data is an offset usually included with function call blobs that offsets dynamic variables (such as strings or byte arrays) to the memory area that encodes them. Here it's only a single memory slot (32-byte) offset from the start of this header block (only skipping the offset itself).
- Since it takes 3 memory slots for the data itself (offset, array length and array) where the array data itself fits into a single slot, we have `32*3=96` plus the remaining 4 bytes for the function signature `96+4=100`, and we reach our elusive 100-byte returndatasize.